# Customize space for vertical table header and table data

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a table below with vertical headers. I'm trying to find a way to remove the extra space inside the table header and table data. Below is how I constructed my table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="field">Item id number:</th>
    <td class="column">XXX 1234 (Location)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field">Values:</th>
    <td class="column">100,000 - 150,000 CM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="field">Item status:</th>
    <td class="column">Passed</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Table image-**

[image]

[Preview link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

I tried resetting the padding and margin for the table header and table row but I don't think that's really the solution to it.

Comment: Looks like you left out your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is combine width and nowrap like that:

```
 .field {
    text-align: start;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 1%;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

[image]

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works. However, how do I know if the header is 10px from the data if I specify a specific width in px or percentage. I was thinking if there's a `gap` or `padding-left` for table header.